# How can I show the total number of elements in ReCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I want to know how to access the other data items in the 'payload' field of recharts from material-ui. I tried looking up but found no references. I want to access the other groupnames and values in the 'return' function

```
const {PieChart, Pie, Sector} = Recharts;
const data = [{name: 'Group B', value: 14},{name: 'Group A', value: 2}, {name: 'Group C', value: 10}];

const renderActiveShape = (props) => {
  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const { cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle,
    fill, payload, percent, value } = props;
  //payload is the data here...
  const sin = Math.sin(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const cos = Math.cos(-RADIAN * midAngle);
  const sx = cx + (outerRadius + 10) * cos;
  const sy = cy + (outerRadius + 10) * sin;
  const mx = cx + (outerRadius + 30) * cos;
  const my = cy + (outerRadius + 30) * sin;
  const ex = mx + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 22;
  const ey = my;
  const textAnchor = cos >= 0 ? 'start' : 'end';

  return (
    <g>
      <text x={cx} y={cy} dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill={fill}>{payload.name}</text>

      {/*I want to know how to access the second element in the payload*/}

      <Sector
        cx={cx}
        cy={cy}
        innerRadius={innerRadius}
        outerRadius={outerRadius}
        startAngle={startAngle}
        endAngle={endAngle}
        fill={fill}
      />
      <Sector
        cx={cx}
        cy={cy}
        startAngle={startAngle}
        endAngle={endAngle}
        innerRadius={outerRadius + 6}
        outerRadius={outerRadius + 10}
        fill={fill}
      />
      <path d={`M${sx},${sy}L${mx},${my}L${ex},${ey}`} stroke={fill} fill="none"/>
      <circle cx={ex} cy={ey} r={2} fill={fill} stroke="none"/>
      <text x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12} y={ey} textAnchor={textAnchor} fill="#333">{`PV ${value}`}</text>
      <text x={ex + (cos >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * 12} y={ey} dy={18} textAnchor={textAnchor} fill="#999">
        {`(Rate ${(percent * 100).toFixed(2)}%)`}
      </text>
    </g>
  );
};

const TwoLevelPieChart = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0,
    };
  },


    render () {
    return (
        <PieChart width={800} height={400} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>
        <Pie 
            activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
          activeShape={renderActiveShape} 
          data={data} 
          cx={300} 
          cy={200} 
          innerRadius={60}
          outerRadius={80} 
          fill="#8884d8"/>
       </PieChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <TwoLevelPieChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: As you can see in the [sources of ReCharts](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/polar/Pie.js#L397) only a single sector get's passed to the function provided to `activeShape` containing the name and the value. You can't access the other datasets from inside this function.

The question is why would you want to access the other datasets in a function that renders the active dataset?

Comment: I want to show the 'total' number of elements inside the piechart, so I need access to that :I

Comment: I see. But you do not want to show the total number inside the currently active shape i guess. Wouldn't it be better to customize the  [`<Legend>`](http://recharts.org/examples/#/en-US/api/Legend) component then? This one has access to the whole dataset...

Comment: See my answer. This is how you could show the total count inside the legend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the whole dataset from inside `renderActiveShape` as it only get's passed a single section of your chart, namely the active section. What you could do is providing a [`<Legend>`](http://recharts.org/examples/#/en-US/api/Legend)component:

```js
const renderLegend = (props) => {
  const { payload } = props;

  return (
    <p>Total count: {payload.length}</p>
  );
}
```

Then inside your Chart:

```js
<Legend content={renderLegend} />
```

Comment: this is what I want to do, so it's working partly but it doesn't work for some edge cases.
http://imgur.com/a/B0uKn  the dataset has 2 entries, I want to show the total of both inside the chart. I hate how this recharts have been designed, it keeps messing up and I'm surprised how the developers give limited access to the data. -_-
Thank you for your comment, I'll give it a try and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after banging my head for a long time, here's the solution:

whatever data you'd like to pass in for your own purpose, just add an extra field in the first object and then use it, example-

```
const data = [{name: 'Group B', value: 14, total: 420, whatever: "myData", kiddingMe: "Yes"},{name: 'Group A', value: 2}, {name: 'Group C', value: 10}];
```

and finally in the piechart, just use `payload.fieldName`